# How to use Redis as a caching System to develop REST API using Node?

Tags: node.js, redis, mongoose, restify

I am developing REST API using Node,Mongoose and restify.I want to use redis as a caching system for API.So Can anyone tell me how to implement this??

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is to:

1. Install redis on your machine. It is its own service. See [redis documentation](http://redis.io/download) for details.
2. Install redis for node. `npm install redis` If you're using default ports, now that package can talk to the redis service running on your machine.
3. Read [node redis documentation](https://www.npmjs.org/package/redis), which is basically just the [redis command documentation](http://redis.io/commands)
4. Store and retrieve stuff in redis from your app. Now it is caching things for you.

There is a little more to it than that, but those are the basics! Determining what data to store, when to retrieve etc will come with practice.

Good luck!